# Skipping tests unless a command line -m parameter was present

Tags: python, pytest

I have my test:

```
import pytest


def test_normal():
    print("normal test runned")
    assert 1 == 1


@pytest.mark.production
def test_production():
    print("production test runned")
    assert 1 == 1
```

I have my conftest.py:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    try:
        parser.addoption('--production', action='store_true', dest="production", default=False, help="enable production tests")
    except ValueError:
        print('option already set')


def pytest_configure(config):
    if not config.option.production:
        setattr(config.option, 'markexpr', 'not production')
```

If i run:

```
pytest some_test.py -v -s
```

Only test_normal runs.

If i run:

```
pytest some_test.py -v -s --production
```

Both tests run.

How do i make it so this command would run both tests:

```
pytest some_test.py -v -s -m 'production'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html) state that you can use `@pytest.mark` alone to achieve what you want:
`@pytest.mark.production` and run `pytest -m production`.

For using `--m` with your approach:

```py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    try:
        parser.addoption('--m', action='store', help="enable production tests")
    except ValueError:
        print('option already set')


def pytest_configure(config):
    if config.option.m != "production":
        setattr(config.option, 'markexpr', 'not production')
```

Comment: This only works if i do pytest some_test.py -v -s --m "production"
But i need: -m "production"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any conftest for that. You can do that from command line directly.
To run only production tests:

`pytest some_test.py -v -s -m 'production'`

To run only non-production tests:
`pytest some_test.py -v -s -m 'not production'`

To run both:
`pytest some_test.py -v -s` or `pytest some_test.py -v -s -m 'production or not production'`

Similarly you can use combination of `and`, `or` and `not` in marker to run any combination of tests.